# why destructor called twice when exception is thrown?

Tags: c++

I am very confused why the destrctor is called twice when excpetion is thrown and which point they are called??

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
class base
{
 public:
     base(){cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;}
     ~base(){cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;}
};
void fun()
{
     throw base(); //<=- Create temp obj of base, and throw exception

}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        fun();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout<<"handle all exception"<<endl;
    }

}
```

following is the output

```
constructor called
destrctor called
handle all exception
destuctor is called
```

But when i added the copy constructor, it never called but destructor called only once so what's happening????

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
class base
{
 public:
     base(){cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;}
     ~base(){cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;}
     base (base &obj){cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;}
};
void fun()
{
     throw base(); //<=- Create temp obj of base, and throw exception
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        fun();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout<<"handle all exception"<<endl;
    }

}
```

output:

```
constructor called
handle all exception
destrctor called
```

Comment: I'd try putting a breakpoint in the destructor and check the stack trace both times, see who's calling it.

Comment: Only thrown once for me with this code.

Comment: Add a copy constructor with a `cout` in it. You should see it being copied.

Comment: http://ideone.com/b8bHo destrctor called only once in this.

Comment: Called twice in vs2010, even when capturing by reference.

Comment: Make your copy constructor standard and see what hppens: `base(base const&)`

Comment: How is `destuctor is called` printed?

Comment: @Martin IF I make handler standard, it would call copy constructor.

Comment: @Alok: I can't seem to make it call the copy constructor. I was just seeing ig it made any difference for you.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler can copy your exception object as many times as it likes. The destructor is called twice because there's a copy.

Comment: +1: The other two answers are wrong, trying to *guess* what goes underneath is irrelevant, the implementation is allowed to copy. Also, both are wrong in their guess both in g++-4.5: no copies performed at all, and VS2010 (according to DanDan): two copies even when catching by reference, hinting that the copy is performed either in the throw or internally.

Answer (score 7):

Because exception object is copied in catch. Use `catch (base&v)` to grab by reference, not value.

Comment: but i am not catching by refernce , you are saying the behavior of catch(...) and catch(base&v) are same??

Comment: This is quite a strong statement. As far as I know, the exception is not being copied in the catch. The answer would be appropriate if the catch was originally `catch ( base b )`. On the other hand, the exception can be copied in the throw: create a local `base` object, copy it to the internal place where the exception is kept alive... until it is caught... but it is still an implementation detail: the implementation can make copies as required (@DeadMG answer is correct)

Comment: @David, I think catch(...) handler doesn't make a copy of object other wise (please see my code above) copy constructor of base class would have been called.

Comment: @Alok: I know, of all things, the `catch (...)` would be the least probable to make a copy, it does not catch by reference, it just does not *catch* anything but the fact that an exception was thrown. That is the point, that the implementation can do as it pleases, and that includes doing different things depending on the presence or absence of non-trivial copy constructors, etc.

Comment: The compiler may make a copy, or as many copies as it likes. You must have a copy constructor available (i.e. not private, but auto generated is ok), and the compiler can copy or optimise out copies as it sees fit. See answer from DeadMG.

Answer (score 1):

Because `catch` block gets a copy of the original object.

To avoid copy, write `try-catch` as:

```
try
{
    fun();
}
catch(const base &e)
{
    cout<<"handle all exception"<<endl;
}
```

I would like to comment on the design as well : user-defined exception class should derive from `std::exception` or one of its derived class.

Comment: Better comment would be do not throw exception at all.

Comment: I believe you know about the linkages embedded by the compiler for handling exceptions.

Comment: @DumbCoder: So what do you suggest as an alternative to exception?

Comment: @Nawaz, catch(...)  => capture the excpetion by reference??

Comment: @Nawaz: Means there will never be need to throw exception? How would you handle error?